# Launch Autocad from .Net

Tags: .net, windows, process, autocad

I'm trying to run an instance of autocad from my .Net code (using System.Diagnostics.Process). So far so good...

However, while the autocad instance is still running, when I click on a drawing file using windows explorer, it launches a NEW instance of autocad, although a running one is already available.

Since I'm using some launch parameters on my own process of autocad (and loading a .NET dll to it), it's important for me that opening a dwg file from windows shell uses the same instance.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This sounds more like an autocad issue than a .NET issue. Does the following link help? https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Double-clicking-a-DWG-file-opens-a-new-instance-of-AutoCAD.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Heinzi for your help.

Changing the file association to Autocad DWG Launcher did solve the problem.

The strange thing is that after doing so, autocad (from the same company and same application package!) still insists to recover the file association to itself.

Anyway, The problem can be marked as SOLVED thanks to Heinzi